# How to predict output of my naive bayes classifier applied on nlp(Restaurant Review) for a single external input text?

Tags: python, nlp

I have a build my naive Bayes classifier model for nlp using bags of word. Now I want to predict output for a single external input
. How can I do it?please find this github link for correction thanks 
https://github.com/Kundan8296/Machine-Learning/blob/master/NLP.ipynb

Comment: thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to post the code here with inputs and what you have tried so we can reproduce that.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read the [help pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help). Helpful may be ["how to ask good questions"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and this [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Users here are way more ready to help if you provide [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with some input and the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply the same preprocessing steps that you applied on your training data, and use it as an input to the classifier. Make sure you don't use fit_transform() on the new data, use transform() only.

```
#Change this part in your preprocessing, so you can keep the original vectorizer.
vect = CountVectorizer(tokenizer=lambda doc: doc, lowercase=False)
bag_of_words = vect.fit_transform(corpus)
...
...
# Now when predicting, use this 
new_data = ... # your new input
new_x = vect.transform(new_data)
y_pred = classifier.predict(new_x)
```

Comment: I have appliied the same code as given above but it generates error."AttributeError: transform not found".please help

Comment: @KUNDANKUMARRoy I added a change to your preprocessing